# Why do we write $f : X \rightarrow Y$ as opposed to $f \in X \rightarrow Y$.

Tags: notation, math-history

I've always been taught to write $f : X \rightarrow Y$ as opposed to $f \in X \rightarrow Y$. This seems weird though, since $X \rightarrow Y$ can be viewed as the set of all functions with source $X$ and target $Y$, in which case the notation $f \in X \rightarrow Y$ has exactly its intended meaning.

Why do we write $f : X \rightarrow Y$? Is it habit? Notational prettiness? Historical accident?

*Related.* In category theory, we write $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ for the set of all arrows $X \rightarrow Y.$ Why do we not write $X \rightarrow Y$ for this set? Again, is this just historical inertia, or is there something deeper going on?

Comment: Who is "viewing X→Y as the set of all such functions with source X and target Y"? I thought this set was $Y^X$.

Comment: But $X\to Y$ is **not** used to represent the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$, so the notation $f\in X\to Y$ can’t be justified on that basis. (I believe that there are some modern mathematical contexts in which the notation $[X\to Y]$ is used, but they’re limited.) The usual notations for that set of functions are $Y^X$ or, better, ${}^XY$.

Comment: Personally, I write $f : X \to Y$ because I'm a type theorist not a set theorist :P

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for with this question, exactly?

Comment: @nik, one kind of answer would demonstrate that viewing $X \rightarrow Y$ as the set of all such functions fails to generalize nicely to other contexts. Another kind of answer would show that, actually, some authors do write $f \in X \rightarrow Y$, and this creates essentially no problems.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. "Fails to generalize nicely": do you mean would there be problems if we wrote $X \to Y$ instead of $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$? It's a bit clunky with respect to operator priority, but otherwise no, what kind of problem could there be? It's just slightly different notation

Comment: Look at it this way, what kind of answer do you think could be given if I asked "Why do we not write the dual of a vector space as $\hat{V}$ instead of $V^*$ or $V^\vee$?" The answer is, we just don't.

Comment: @nik, for example it could be that $* : * \rightarrow *$ very much needs to be seen as a ternary relation, as opposed to a binary operation $* \rightarrow *$ followed by a membership claim. There may be contexts where the latter viewpoint *simply doesn't work*. This would explain why we distinguish the binary operation $\mathrm{Hom}$ from the ternary relation $* : * \rightarrow *$.

Comment: @Ben: I know that you meant that as a joke, but I have never met any set theorist to write that way. So I can't even begin to find your comment funny, and it takes some effort to find it not mildly offensive.

Comment: @Asaf When I read Ben Millwood's comment my first thought (not knowing anything about type theory) was that $f \in X \to Y$ looks like something a type theorist might write (_i.e._ writing $X \to Y$ for $Y^X$.)  So now he can be offended too :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, not that its any of my business, but I really don't think he was trying to be offensive.

Comment: @user18921: I know he wasn't trying to be offensive. I see the `:P` there, and I did my best to not write my comment for nearly three hours now.

Comment: @user18921 : I'm going to jump on the bandwagon and say that, to the best of my knowledge, nobody has ever "viewed $X \to Y$ as the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$".  There are already at least two accepted notations for that set of functions, which many people have been using for many years.  "$X \to Y$" doesn't look like that set of functions, at least to me, any more than $Y^X$ does.

Comment: @Asaf, props for holding out for so long. But, I think this is based on a misunderstanding. He's saying "you know what? We're not so different. You write $\in$ for membership. We write $:$. Sure, you formalize it in the theory, we in the metatheory, but really we are not so different."

Comment: @AsafKaragila: My apologies! I would certainly have not made the comment if I'd suspected it might upset you. I'll not delete it now though because then none of the following discussion would make sense.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If a type theorist ever says anything that offends you, just ask him why we're all still using QWERTY keyboards ^_^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There would be at least two problems with the notation $f \in X \to Y$ instead of $f : X\to Y$ to mean "$f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$."

1. In general it's bad for clarity to write things that have initial segments that mean unrelated things.  Here "$f \in X$" is an initial segment of "$f \in X \to Y$" and if $X$ is a long expression, the reader might be surprised upon reaching the arrow and need to go back and re-interpret what came before it in light of what is ultimately claimed about the relationship between $f$ and $X$.
2. The arrow is also used sometimes for other things such as logical implication and convergence, so authors should make sure to provide contextual clues that enable the reader to resolve the ambiguity.  The colon in the expression $f:X \to Y$ helps the reader understand what the arrow means.  On the other hand, the notation "$f \in X \to Y$" is bad because $f \in X$ could be interpreted as a proposition, which is consistent with the use of "$\to$" to mean logical implication.

Comment: Yes, and imagine a sequence of functions from $x_n$ to $x$. $f_n\in x_n\to x$. As $n\to\infty$, $f_n\to f$ pointwise...

Comment: Or, you know, worse. Consider $\varphi$ and $\psi$ to be two sets, now consider the following: $$f\in\varphi\to\psi\leftrightarrow\forall x\in\varphi\exists!y\in\psi:\langle x,y\rangle\in f$$ It's fun to come up with ways to make this notation very hard to parse! But I'll stop here (unless I come up with an amazing example next, which is unlikely).

Comment: @Asaf Ack!  Well, that's also a reason not to use $\varphi$ and $\psi$ as variable symbols in set theory.

Comment: True. But in some places [in set theory] those are commonly used symbols for functions (e.g. Galvin-Hajnal theorem and related areas), and functions are sets.

Comment: Re initial segments, $f \in Y$ is also an initial segment of $f \in Y^X$...

Comment: @ZhenLin That is a good point, so maybe (1) is only a valid reason in combination with (2).  (And the superscript notation is less ambiguous than the arrows, at least in the kind of writing I've seen.)